# ADO .Net / C# Database Connection Pools

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, timeout

If i set TimeOut=10, SqlCommandTimeout=100 in ADO.Net connection, if my query takes more than 10 secs, say 50s, do i get result back or connection timeout will happen?

Comment: Did you try out and what is the result?

Comment: sorry to say but if your query takes 50secs you need to fix the query

Comment: There are some valid scenarios. Say with huge database running as backend scheduled job during non-working hours are possible. This may be invoked from an report engine to send auto report. But i agree. Some query tuning can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are several time outs in ADO.Net.
There is a `TimeOut` for connection attempts (i.e. how much time to wait for a connection to the database to be created),
and there is as `TimeOut` for Command executions (i.e. how much time to wait for a command to be executed and return it's result)

I don't know what is the first `TimeOut` you wrote about, but the `SqlCommandTimeout` is the amount of seconds to wait for the SQL command to be executed, therefor you should get a result back since the time out you specified is longer then the time the actual command was running.

Answer (score 0):

Result will come if the connection is success. TimeOut is the connection timeout. (Time taken to connect to SQL Server). Once the connection succeeds, if the query started executing for 50 seconds, it will return the result because the SQL Command Timeout is 100 seconds.